# R: tobit with a varying censoring level (cnreg equivalent)

Tags: r, statistics

I have county-level data from each of the 50 states, and each state suppresses data differently. I've been looking everywhere to find a way to do a tobit-type regression in R that can account for the different censoring levels.

I've found out that in STATA you can do this with cnreg, so I'm wondering if there's an equivalent package in r, or any way to do it, maybe with censReg?